# why wont this visual basic script work?

Tags: vb.net

i am getting really annoyed by this piece of code for visual basic
please can you help. i have looked on YouTube and everywhere else even the vb website!!! i would really appreciate it if someone could help me out

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MessageBox.Show("Hi!!")
    Timer1.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub ProgressBar1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ProgressBar1.Click
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    ProgressBar1.Increment(1)
    If ProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        MsgBox("Jeff")

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
End Sub


Private Function GetNumericUpDown1(v As Integer) As Boolean
End Function

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ( : ( ) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Well Done!")


    End If
End Sub



Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    MessageBox.Show("!!Stopped!!")
    Timer2.Stop()

End Sub

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    ProgressBar2.Increment(0.6)
    If ProgressBar2.Value = 100 Then
        Timer2.Stop()
        MsgBox("Jeff")

    End If
End Sub


Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    MessageBox.Show("!!Started!!")
    Timer2.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub SplitContainer1_Panel1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles SplitContainer1.Panel1.Paint

End Sub

Private Sub NotifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub TreeView1_AfterSelect(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs)

End Sub




Private Sub Timer3_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer3.Tick
    ProgressBar3.Increment(1)
    If ProgressBar3.Value = 100 Then
        Timer3.Stop()


    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Timer3.Start()


End Sub

Private Sub ProgressBar3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ProgressBar3.Click

End Sub
End Class
```

BTW:this is my first post so it is probably rubbish!!

Comment: Perhaps you'd be kind enough to explain what's wrong?

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: on tabcontrol1 the 3rd tab i cant get button4 and progressbar3 to work.

Comment: And what does _"can't get it to work"_ mean exactly? You have to be specific, we have no idea what's working here and whatnot, nor do we know what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough points to comment.

First off, as others have said we can't recreate this since we have no idea what your Form looks like or what you are expecting it to do.

Secondly, you should turn on Option Strict in the Compile section of Project properties to avoid technical errors like ProgressBar2.Increment(0.6) since 0.6 isn't a valid integer.

I threw together a TabControl (which you never mentioned in the OP) with 3 tabs and the various buttons and progress bars you list in what seemed like a logical fashion to me and it ran just fine for what code you have. Clicked the button on each tab and each progress bar eventually got to 100%. I have no idea what else you were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove all the empty subs and action listeners, it would be easier to detect the problem